# How can I use the int pointers in the parameter of the function to get the indices of the largest value in the 2d array and return the pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
double * matrix_max_1(double mat[][COL], int r, int* pi, int* pj) {

    double * ptrmat = 0;

    double max = 0;


    for (pi = 0; *pi <= ROW; pi++)
        for (pj = 0; *pj <= COL; pj++) {
           if (mat[*pi][*pj] > *ptrmat) {

                ptrmat = &mat[*pi][*pj];




            }


        }

    return ptrmat;
}
```

the int r parameter in the function should be used as the number of rows but i already defined a constant ROW. The main purpose of this function is to return a pointer to the largest element in a 2d array. when I run it in current form the program crashes.

Comment: Think about what value `ptrmat` has the first time you compare with `*ptrmat`. Also, an array with `K` elements is indexed from `0` to `K - 1`.

Comment: `for (pi = 0; *pi <= ROW; pi++)` setting `pi` to a NULL pointer, and immediately dereferencing the null, is not exactly getting off to a good start. You might as well just write `int *pi=0; *pi` and get rid of the middle-man...

Comment: `double * ptrmat = 0;  if (mat[*pi][*pj] > *ptrmat)` And dereferencing  a NULL pointer there isn't a good idea too.

Comment: Also note that `*pi` and `*pj` will not store what you think they will store. Use local variables for looping, don't touch `*pi` and `*pj` except for storing the answer.

Comment: And incrementing `pi` and `pj` makes no sense at all. (That's a pretty impressive amount of bugs in such a small function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with this.

```
double * ptrmat = 0;
```

is not a very good value to start with; you're going to need to compare it to the null pointer every time you want to dereference it.

```
double max = 0;
```

is also not a very good starting value - what if all the elements are negative?

```
for (pi = 0; *pi <= ROW; pi++)
```

is nonsense.
`pi` is a pointer to where you're supposed to store the result.
Here, you're overwriting it with the null pointer and immediately dereferencing it.
Incrementing `pi` doesn't make any sense either.
(Even if you fixed this, `*pi = 0` and `(*pi)++`, you'd be overwriting `*pi` unconditionally, not storing the index of the maximum but the index where the loop terminated.)

Also, the maximum valid index is `r - 1`, not `ROW`.
The maximum valid index for the next loop is `COL - 1`, not `COL`.

```
if (mat[*pi][*pj] > *ptrmat)
```

This will fail if you fix the other errors because `ptrmat` is the null pointer on the first iteration.

Instead,

- Assume that the first matrix element is the maximum.
- Loop using local variables, and only store their values in the "out" parameters when you know the answer.

Something like this:

```
double* matrix_max_1(double matrix[][COL], int rows, int* row, int* column) {
    int max_row = 0;
    int max_column = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] > matrix[max_row][max_column]) {
                max_row = i;
                max_column = j
            }
        }
    }
    if (row != nullptr) {
        *row = max_row;
    }
    if (column != nullptr) {
        *column = max_column
    }

    return &matrix[max_row][max_column];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. I didn't know about the null pointer before as I'm still a beginner as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of indices is totally bogus:

```
   for (pi = 0; *pi <= ROW; pi++)
```

pi is a pointer set to 0, then you dereference it thereafter with *pi <= ROW ?
Same for pj...
Also what are *pj and *pi for?

Use indices like this:

```
 double* currentMax = &mat[0][0];
 for (size_t i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            if (mat[i][j] > *currentMax) {...
```